# In Excel, how do I stack a very large set of columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[No Visual Basic please]

In Excel 365, I have a large number of dynamic arrays in columns, side by side, of different lengths, but all starting in the same row. For illustration purposes, assume that the first starts in A1, and the last starts in Z1 (in practice I have many more than just 26 columns). I'd like to stack them into a single column dynamic array, starting in AB1, say.

I know I can do the following:

```
AB1 = VSTACK(A1#,B1#,C1#,...,Z1#)
```

but that means typing in 10 arrays (and as I say, in my actual example there are a lot more than 26).

**Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to type in each array?**

(Again, no VB solutions please. If needed, I can already figure something out that way but I'd prefer to stick to pure Excel if possible.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it with `=TOCOL(TRANSPOSE(A1#:Z1#))`

I didn't test with different array lengths...

Comment: Ah, very cool! I did try with different lengths. It appears to limit the inclusion of columns to no more than the length of A1#, so unless A1# s the longest array, or one of them, it'll miss some entries. One way to fix that is to ignore the dynamic nature of the arrays and do something like `=TCOL(TRANSPOSE(A1:An:Z1:Zn))` where n is the length of the longest array. It then needs some cleanup to remove blanks from the shorter arrays (e.g. using FILTER()), but it's still a neat solution. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one ,,,,, +10 ☺

Comment: using a recurvise lambda type function like `BYCOL()` may be another option